# Output compiler error to a txt file in python

Tags: python, regex, compiler-construction

I'm a beginner using python. I want to create a regular expression to capture error messages from compiler output in python. How would I do this?

for example, if the compiler output is the following error message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "sample.py", line 1, in <module>
    hello
NameError: name 'hello' is not defined
```

I want to be able to only extract only the following string from the output:

```
NameError: name 'hello' is not defined
```

In this case there is only one error, however I want to extract all the errors the compiler outputs. How do I do this using regular expressions? Or if there is an easier way, I'm open to suggestions

Comment: `NameError` is a runtime error, not a compile time error. Python only ever shows you the first error encountered, unless you are catching exceptions and are writing their tracebacks to a console explicitly.

Comment: Is there a way to extract this error using a regular expression, I'm storing the console output in a txt

Comment: The error text is always preced by `Traceback` at the start of a line, and the exception is the *next* line with text at the start. Extrapolate from there. :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
r'Traceback \(most recent call last\):\n(?:[ ]+.*\n)*(\w+: .*)'
```

should extract your exception; a traceback contains lines that all start with whitespace except for the exception line.

The above matches the literal text of the traceback first line, 0 or more lines that start with at least one space, and then captures the line following that provided it starts with 1 or more word characters (which fits Python identifiers nicely), a colon, and then the rest up to the end of a line.

Demo:

```
>>> import re
>>> sample = '''\
... Traceback (most recent call last):
...   File "sample.py", line 1, in <module>
...     hello
... NameError: name 'hello' is not defined
... '''
>>> re.search(r'Traceback \(most recent call last\):\n(?:[ ]+.*\n)*(\w+: .*)', sample).groups()
("NameError: name 'hello' is not defined",)
```